# Expected argument of type "App\Entity\PageParagraph", "array" given at property path "paragraphs"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to create a `ManyToMany` relationship, so I have `Page` entity which contains the `paragraphs` property:

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(
    targetEntity: PageParagraph::class,
    cascade: ["persist", "remove"],
    orphanRemoval: true
)]
#[ORM\OrderBy(["position" => "ASC"])]
private Collection $paragraphs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->paragraphs = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

and within the form builder I added this:

```
->add('paragraphs', CollectionType::class, array(
    'entry_type'   => PageParagraphType::class,
    'allow_add'    => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
    'allow_delete' => true
))
```

basically now I have a component that allow me to create n `paragraphs` when I'm creating a page. In the controller of `Page` I wrote this:

```
#[Route('/new', methods: ['GET', 'POST'], name: 'admin_pages_new')]
public function new (Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
{
    $entity = new Page();
    $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager->persist($entity);
        $entityManager->flush();

        return $this->redirect(
            $this->generateUrl('admin_pages_show', array('id' => $entity -> getId()))
        );

        if ($link = $entity->getExternalLink()) {
            return $this->redirect($link);
        }

        return $this->render('/frontend/loadPage.html.twig', array(
            'page' => $entity,
            'entity' => $entity
        ));
    }

    return $this -> render('/admin/pages/new.html.twig', [
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form -> createView(),
    ]);
}
```

but for some reason I get this error:

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\PageParagraph", "array" given at property path "paragraphs".

on this line: `$form -> handleRequest($request);`

I tried to inspect the content using: `dd($request->request->all())` and I have this `paragraphs` structure:

```
"paragraphs" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:4 [▼
        "title_it" => "test"
        "published" => "1"
        "position" => ""
         "body_it" => "<p>hello world</p>"
    ]
]
```

Isn't symfony supposed to convert the array automatically when the request is handled? How can I fix this?

***UPDATE***

Twig file:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div id="paragraphs_holder" data-label="New paragraph"
            class="fields timeline col-xs-12"
            data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.paragraphs.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for paragraph in form.paragraphs %}
            <div class="prototype_container col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                <div class="timeline-panel">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
                            data-target="#collapseExample{{ loop.index }}"
                            aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                        Dettagli Paragrafo
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample{{ loop.index }}">
                        <hr/>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            {{ form_row(paragraph.title_it) }}
                            {{ form_row(paragraph.published) }}
                            {{ form_row(paragraph.position) }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12">
                            {{ form_row(paragraph.body_it) }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {%- endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you update the schema and clear the cache?

Comment: @ArleighHix yes everything is updated

Comment: Can you provide the twig as well?

Comment: @JimmyFound yes, question updated

Comment: I would suspect the `PageParagraphType` to have no `data_class` set and thus defaulting to providing an array.

Comment: @Jakumi thanks, you pointed me in the right way, I posted an answer with the solution based on your comment. If you write your own answer I will accept it, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [Jakumi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4275413/jakumi) comment that point me in the right direction, I was able to fix the issue.

So within `PageParagraphType` I had to specify this:

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
  $resolver->setDefaults(array(
    'data_class' => PageParagraph::class,
  ));
}
```

in order to allow Symfony to convert the array to a `PageParagraph` entity automatically.